# Upload a File name with more than one spaces it's automatically convert into single space

Tags: coldfusion, cfml, lucee

I have uploaded file name as "**Front  page.jpg**". Here there are **two spaces between** Front & page on my original file.

When I submit the form, The **cffile.SERVERFILE** comes up with **Front page.jpg** only **single space** between Front & page.

Here the file uploaded as it's original name ( double spaces between Front & page ) in my file explore but the server file return only single space between the both string.

Now, I want to pass this SERVERFILE name into my second action page & on the second action page , I should check the specific file exist or not. When I check my recent upload file( Front  page.jpg ) does not exits. Because my SERVERFILE return only single space between the both string.

How I can escape from this issue.

Make sure,

1. I have used pre tag to display the file name - It's display good with double spaces.
2. As per client requirement I should not have a permission to rename the file with underscore( _ ) or some other delimeter to avoid space.
3. I want to pass my file name with more than one space to another page. That's my requirement.
   [image]

My sample code here :

```
if( cgi.REQUEST_METHOD == "post" ) {
       tempDir = expandPath( "./temp" ) & "/";
       if( !directoryExists( tempDir ) ) directoryCreate( tempDir );

        
        fileData = fileUpload( tempDir, "fileField", "*", "makeunique" );
        writeoutput( "Display with Pre tag : <pre>#fileData.serverFile#</pre>" );
        writeoutput( "Display without Pre tag : #fileData.serverFile#" );

        writeDump( fileData );
    }
```

Comment: Does it show multiple spaces if you check in view source in browser?

Comment: Why not just save hassle and replace the spaces with underscore or something to keep the filename a whole string?

Comment: @rrk, Browser console having multiple spaces.  But when we pass that value into next action page, it will changed as single spaces.

Comment: @haxtbh, As I mentioned in the descriptions we could not overwrite the user original file name. Meaning we don't have a permission to replace it with underscore.

Comment: You'll encountered more problems.  Some filenames are illegal, some may contain UTF-8 or high ASCII whitespace characters. We convert filenames to ASCII7 and then sluggify IF the original filename must be used. We prefer store the file using a unique hash name and then retain the original filename in the database for use with AHREF download attribute or renaming via CFHEADER/CFCONTENT during download.

Comment: "To pass a value with spaces to another page"... you mean using a URL variable?  If so, use the encodeasurlattribute() to encode the spaces.

Comment: Agree with @JamesMoberg, you should save the file with a UUID as the name, then store the "file name" in a database so you can display that in the UI or when the file is downloaded. You could allow a user to rename the file by just changing the label in the DB. The actual filename would never change.

Comment: An image-related scenario that may cause problems... "choose file" allows selecting a photo from mobile devices. We've seen these get uploaded as HEIC/HEIF instead of JPG/JPEG (and perform auto-conversion as needed), but the user usually has no idea they are uploading a non-JPG image. If you need to convert, you'll need to use a non-CF approach.  (We chose to use ImageMagick and convert it via CFExecute.)

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why, but when I tried to replicate this I also had the double spaces reduced to single spaces within the form scope.

Instead, use the getHttpRequestData method, and you should see `serverfile=Front++page.jpg` in the content. I have had several issues with ColdFusion manipulating http request data, but getHttpRequestData has always worked as expected.